# Netty Client requests timing out while sending to multiple servers

Tags: java, netty, future

First, I will explain the background:
I have implemented Netty Framework and having a single client sending HTTP request to more than 44 servers. The servers are responding to that request.
In my client, I am sending request by overriding `channelActive` function and reading response from `channelRead0` function and storing all responses in a data structure.
Since, sending HTTP request and getting response from 44 servers takes time. I am using a timeout value and the structure looks like below:

```
      for (final InetAddress target : remoteIPAddresses.values()) {
            httpClient.connect(target);
        }
        // wait for the timeout. Hoping client send request to all
        // the targets and get response.
        Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        httpClient.stop();
        fetchResults();
```

fetchResults fetched the results from the data structure mentioned in `channelRead0`
 The connect method contains netty implementation which looks like below:

```
 public void connect(final InetAddress remoteAddress){
        new Bootstrap()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectionTimeout)
            .option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
            .group(eventLoopGroup)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(httpNettyClientChannelInitializer)
            .connect(remoteAddress, serverPort)
            .addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                        future.cancel(!future.isSuccess());
                    }
                });
    }
```

**Parameters used within Netty**

```
connectionTimeout = 100ms  
Timeout value = 400ms    
Eventloop = 1 (Tried with 2 , 5 and 10)
```

**Problem**
Out of 44 targets, I am getting timeouts for multiple targets. The targets varies everytime. Using thread sleep is not a good practice and I am not able to figure out any other way to achieve the task.
Is there a better way to do this? I have already saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GRIyCMNGGI) video. I am blocked. Any lead will be really helpful.

Comment: Which timeout is getting triggered? Is it CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS or the aggregate timeout you're setting? Depending on the servers' response characteristics, 400ms may be too little

Comment: CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS is 100 ms and ReadTimeout is 400 ms. edited question in response to this comment too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sleeping and hoping that you have all the required responses, you can use a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Pass this latch to your handler, which will count it down every time a response arrives (in `channelRead0`). Your main thread can then wait for all responses with a global timeout with `await()`

Your handler can look like:

```
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class HttpResponseHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpObject> {

    final CountDownLatch responseLatch;

    public HttpResponseHandler(CountDownLatch responseLatch) {
        this.responseLatch = responseLatch;
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpObject msg) throws Exception {
        ....
        responseLatch.countDown();
    }
}
```

And in the main thread:

```
        CountDownLatch responseLatch = new CountDownLatch(remoteIpAddresses.size());
        HttpResponseHandler handler = new HttpResponseHandler(responseLatch);
        // your for loop to connect to servers here
        responseLatch.await(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I haven't taken into account error conditions in the handler (socket connect/read timeout, invalid response etc), so make sure to handle those.

Comment: Depending on the number of servers, Is it a good practice to increase event loops. Currently, I am using 1